# Object in PHP array with a lot of text won't echo

Tags: php

I have the following `PHP` that retrieves info from a database about heart diseases and adds the info to a `JSON Array` to be used in an `Android` app.

All `objects` in the `array` are echoing properly individually but when it comes to `disease_info`, nothing is being echoed.

`disease_info` is of `TEXT` type and holds a lot of text, about 400-500 words, and also has line breaks like `\n` to organize the text in the app.

What might be the problem in the `disease_info` field that is making it not to be echoed?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$qry = "SELECT * FROM heart_diseases WHERE home = 'yes'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);

$arr = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $object["diseaseID"] = $row["disease_id"];
  $object["diseaseName"] = $row["disease_name"];
  $object["diseaseInfo"] = $row["disease_info"];
  $object["diseaseImageURL"] = $row["disease_image_url"];

  array_push($arr, $object);
}

echo json_encode($arr);

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) requires that every single string is in UTF-8. Try running [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) or [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to see the actual error.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! So what's the UTF-8 encoding for `\n`?

Comment: Since UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII, the encoding is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an array, I echoed line by line from the table and handled it appropriately using a `readLine()` method.

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$qry = "SELECT * FROM heart_diseases WHERE home = 'yes'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo $row[0]."\n".$row[1]."\n".$row[2]."\n".$row[3]."\n".$row[4]."\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "empty";
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

$conn->close();
?>
```